# Is this voicing for Dmin7 right?

Tags: chord-theory, instrumentation, chord-voicings

I am transferring a Basie chart into Finale.

(A) For a 'Clean' copy and, (B) to study Frank Foster's process.

The 'chart' in question is "Shiny Stockings".

This is an ensemble passage where the written chord is Dmin7. The notes used in the chord include D, F, A, C, E natural. The Trombone voicing (bottom to top) is D, C, E naural, F, with a minor second (E-F) in the top 2 voices and the 5th omitted. The voicing would indicate a D min 11. Wouldn't it have been more harmonious (and more strictly in the chord) to voice it as D, A, C, F - if the goal is to have the F in the first trombone?

I guess my question is: Am I looking at a mistake, or is this what was intended? That concert E natural is voiced in the saxes and trumpets as well and the first IS represented in the 4th trumpet.

Comment: D F A C E is D minor 9, not 11.

Comment: It is not uncommon for jazz chords to be written in a simpler form than they are actually executed. When you see a Dm7 on a chord chart, you may wind up adding other tensions to the chord, such as a Dm9.

Answer (score 1):

It may just be a typo, as the chord spells *Dm9* rather than Dm7 (or Dm11). The voicing missing P5 is pretty common, and it would appear that the dissonance of a m2 (E>F) was on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but it is probably correct. Dissonance buried inside of a voicing can add a lot of character to a chord voicing, and the 9th (E in this case) is a common extension for a minor 7th chord.

I recommend listening to a recording Basie's band performing this chart, and see what it sounds like.